# How to perform arithmetic operations on selected fields in Perl

Tags: perl

I am in a basic stage of learning Perl and have a task to perform. I need to subtract a number in a field from other numbers in other fields within a file and have the difference placed in the numbers I'm subtracting from. I could depict this as below

```
03,12682559,USD,010,11398,,,015,11398,,,030,11398,,,
16,698,416667,V,110729,,1354409,2011060411/
88,XX:XXXX XXX
88,TE:56745745
88,VBDS:4564574
16,195,416667,V,110729,,3134046323,SD06546700S1DA01/
88,ED:BMG RECD
88,ED:2097675
88,DRGF:D5674D6756
88,CV:O/O XXXXX XXXX XXX XX
88,AB:XXXX
88,BO:ABCL VSSFRDE SERV WESF 12700 Wdftgs 
88,OA:USD416667
88,BO:5676476 BO1:gfhdghj fhfjhjdd SERV TKDF 
49,2151723,15/
98,2151723,3,21/
```

First, I need to search for the account number which in this case is **12682559** (I have to perform the operation for this account only) on the first line, starting **03**.

Next I need to take the number **416667** from line starting **88** which looks like **88,OA:USD416667** in the file.

This number is to be subtracted from the value in the two lines starting **49** and **98** and the difference replaced without disturbing the other elements of these lines.

Comment: The first numbers are probably not line numbers but describe the type of data that is stored in that line if I see this correctly.

Comment: You are not really learning Perl: You took on a job that is beyond your capacity, and you want someone else to do it for you now while you get paid. That does not mean no one will answer your question. But, you should at least put a little effort into at least formatting and composing your question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are looking to get the data from a file, in which case, you'll want to read up on   how Perl does IO:

```
perldoc -f io
```

You can parse those lines yourself, or you could use a module such as [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)

Once you have the pieces parsed, you can do whatever operations you need and write the data back out to file, etc.

Since you are getting started, here's [one book](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_00.html#toc_UHJlZmFjZQ) that you might consider reading.

You might also spend some time [here](http://learn.perl.org/).

Comment: I don't seem to have the IO documentation with the perl version i'am using. since this requires some advance coding, Could you please help me with the first lines so that i can dig in more --thanks again

Comment: The docs are online as well.  See: http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html and this for the file open: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Comment: @Craig: It is generally best to `use Text::CSV`, which will pick the best backend available - either XS or pure Perl.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the first numbers are part of the file itself